# Converting string to int is too slow

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I've got a program that reads in 3 strings per line for 50000. It then does other things. The part that reads the file and converts to integers is taking 80% of the total running time.

My code snippet is below:

```
import time
file = open ('E:/temp/edges_big.txt').readlines()
start_time = time.time()
for line in file[1:]:
    label1, label2, edge = line.strip().split()
    # label1 = int(label1); label2 = int(label2); edge = float(edge)
    # Rest of the loop deleted
print ('processing file took ', time.time() - start_time, "seconds")
```

The above takes about **0.84 seconds**. Now, when I uncomment the line

```
label1 = int(label1);label2 = int(label2);edge = float(edge)
```

the runtime rises to about **3.42 seconds**.

The input file is in the form: `str1 str2 str3` per line

Are the functions `int()` and `float()` that slow? How could I optimize this?

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two lines that causes such a large difference in runtime; can you clarify?

Comment: This is odd. On my machine, two `int()` calls and one `float()` call take about 1.7us in total. This times 50000 is 85ms. This makes yours 30x slower than mine. That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Also, "*about* 0.8440001010894775 seconds"? SCNR...

Comment: To echo what Tim said, could you clearly state which two versions you are comparing? Right now you have the conversions in the code, but have the `append()` commented out. You then suggest that when you add the conversions in, the timings change. Either I am misinterpreting this completely, or there are clearly some typos.

Comment: I suggest updating the post with profiling information and also timing with python's `timeit` module.

Comment: NPE, I'm comparing the code with "label1 = int(label1);label2 = int(label2);edge = float(edge)" and without it. Without the line that converts the str into ints, the code runs very fast. If I add the line that converts the str into ints, it slows down considerably. I'm leaving the "append" for now since it doens't seem to have problems. James

Comment: Your comment contradicts what you've written in the question. Please edit the question to show *exactly* what the difference is between the two versions you're comparing.

Comment: My apologies Tim! The question has been edited

Comment: If I were you, I'd see how much time goes into each of the three conversions. Also, I'd come up with a small self-contained runnable test case that demonstrates the slowness and that we can experiment with.

Comment: What Python 3.x version? Here's what I see from a quick trial: 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3 all run 0.033 without the conversions. With the conversions, I get: 2.7 - 0.125s; 3.1 - 0.162s; 3.2 - 0.155s, 3.3 - 0.10s. For 3.1 and 3.2, that's a slowdown of 5, and 0.84 x 5 ~ 4s.

Answer (score 4):

If the file is in OS cache then parsing the file takes milliseconds on my machine:

```
name                                 time ratio comment
read_read                        145 usec  1.00 big.txt
read_readtxt                    2.07 msec 14.29 big.txt
read_readlines                  4.94 msec 34.11 big.txt
read_james_otigo                29.3 msec 201.88 big.txt
read_james_otigo_with_int_float 82.9 msec 571.70 big.txt
read_map_local                  93.1 msec 642.23 big.txt
read_map                        95.6 msec 659.57 big.txt
read_numpy_loadtxt               321 msec 2213.66 big.txt
```

Where the `read_*()` functions are:

```
def read_read(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        data = file.read()

def read_readtxt(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as file:
        text = file.read()

def read_readlines(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

def read_james_otigo(filename):
    file = open (filename).readlines()
    for line in file[1:]:
        label1, label2, edge = line.strip().split()

def read_james_otigo_with_int_float(filename):
    file = open (filename).readlines()
    for line in file[1:]:
        label1, label2, edge = line.strip().split()
        label1 = int(label1); label2 = int(label2); edge = float(edge)

def read_map(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        L = [(int(l1), int(l2), float(edge))
             for line in file
             for l1, l2, edge in [line.split()] if line.strip()]

def read_map_local(filename, _i=int, _f=float):
    with open(filename) as file:
        L = [(_i(l1), _i(l2), _f(edge))
             for line in file
             for l1, l2, edge in [line.split()] if line.strip()]

import numpy as np

def read_numpy_loadtxt(filename):
    a = np.loadtxt('big.txt', dtype=[('label1', 'i'),
                                     ('label2', 'i'),
                                     ('edge', 'f')])
```

And `big.txt` is generated using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

n = 50000
a = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=1<<10, size=2*n).reshape(-1, 2)
np.savetxt('big.txt', np.c_[a, np.random.rand(n)], fmt='%i %i %s')
```

It produces 50000 lines:

```
150 952 0.355243621018
582 98 0.227592557278
478 409 0.546382780254
46 879 0.177980983303
...
```

To reproduce results, [download the code](https://gist.github.com/4276624) and run:

```sh
# write big.txt
python generate-file.py
# run benchmark
python read-array.py
```

Comment: I'm surprised that the numpy loadtxt version is so much slower than the alternatives -- any idea what's going on there?

Comment: @EdwardLoper: no idea. What results do you get on your machine?

Comment: I get the same results you do -- loadtxt is much slower.  It just surprises me, because I thought the whole point of loadtxt was that it was written in c so it could be fast.  Though upon further investigation, I might have been misinformed on that -- it may be written in python after all, in which case I would definitely expect it to be slower.

Comment: Here's its definition: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/browser/trunk/numpy/lib/npyio.py?rev=8452#L500 -- so now it makes sense to me that it is slow.  I guess it's more there for convenience then, not for fast data loading.

Comment: Edward, I'm getting error below about encoding: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xb5' in file E:\reporttime.py on line 37, but no encoding declared`

Comment: @JamesOtigo: the encoding is declared, look at [the first line in `reporttime.py`](https://gist.github.com/4276624#file-reporttime-py). Anyway `utf-8` is the default encoding in Python 3 (the code works both Python 2 and 3)

Comment: @EdwardLoper: Yes, I've found only pure Python version of [`numpy.loadtxt()` on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L610)

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to get almost same timings as yours. I think the problem was with my code that was doing the timings:

```
read_james_otigo                  40 msec big.txt
read_james_otigo_with_int_float  116 msec big.txt
read_map                         134 msec big.txt
read_map_local                   131 msec big.txt
read_numpy_loadtxt               400 msec big.txt
read_read                        488 usec big.txt
read_readlines                  9.24 msec big.txt
read_readtxt                    4.36 msec big.txt

name                                 time ratio comment
read_read                        488 usec  1.00 big.txt
read_readtxt                    4.36 msec  8.95 big.txt
read_readlines                  9.24 msec 18.95 big.txt
read_james_otigo                  40 msec 82.13 big.txt
read_james_otigo_with_int_float  116 msec 238.64 big.txt
read_map_local                   131 msec 268.05 big.txt
read_map                         134 msec 274.87 big.txt
read_numpy_loadtxt               400 msec 819.42 big.txt


read_james_otigo                39.4 msec big.txt
read_readtxt                    4.37 msec big.txt
read_readlines                  9.21 msec big.txt
read_map_local                   131 msec big.txt
read_james_otigo_with_int_float  116 msec big.txt
read_map                         134 msec big.txt
read_read                        487 usec big.txt
read_numpy_loadtxt               398 msec big.txt

name                                 time ratio comment
read_read                        487 usec  1.00 big.txt
read_readtxt                    4.37 msec  8.96 big.txt
read_readlines                  9.21 msec 18.90 big.txt
read_james_otigo                39.4 msec 80.81 big.txt
read_james_otigo_with_int_float  116 msec 238.51 big.txt
read_map_local                   131 msec 268.84 big.txt
read_map                         134 msec 275.11 big.txt
read_numpy_loadtxt               398 msec 816.71 big.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this at all.

I have generated a file of 50000 lines, containing three random numbers (two ints, one float) on each line, separated by spaces.

I then ran your script on that file. The original script finishes in 0.05 seconds on my three-year-old PC, the script with the uncommented line takes 0.15 seconds to finish. Of course it takes longer to do string to int/float conversions, but certainly not at the scale of several seconds. Unless your target machine is a toaster running embedded Windows CE.

Comment: Tim, it's actually a new machine with core i7 , 64 bits. I will try using a different file and update