# I/O optimization for Python

Tags: python, performance, io, built-in, chunks

I'm writing a program that takes in multiple lines of codes. At the moment, I am processing each one separately -> as each line comes in, I strip it, store it, etc., before asking for the next line via the sys.stdin.readline() method. I was wondering if there was a way to improve my efficiency, as my program is currently too slow. Is it faster to just take all the lines at once(I know how many lines I am expecting), store them in a list and then process them? If so, is there any one built in function that is built for speed and can do this efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: How did you conclude your program is "slow"?

Comment: Its for a programming competition and I received an error upon submission.

Comment: The function that's built for speed that can do this efficiently is called `readline` (or, if you want to be more idiomatic, `next`). File reading uses a buffer, and only does I/O when it gets to the end of the buffer. It's not that likely that `readline` is your actual problem. But without knowing anything else about your program, it's hard to say any more than that.

Comment: Also, instead of guessing, or asking others to guess, why not try testing? Just write it both ways—one line at a time, and all at once—and use `timeit` to compare the two. Then you'll know for sure which is faster, which is a lot more useful than knowing that some guy on the internet suspected one might be faster than the other.

Comment: abarnert, I dont know what the file name would be. The rules only qualify that it will be "standard stdin procedure"

Comment: Also, timeit has not been very effective for my purposes. Do you know any other python timer method?

Comment: You could try posting your code so we can take a look at it...

Comment: you could [adapt this code to compare time performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13861768/4279)

Answer (score 1):

You could speed things up a bit by reading all the lines in at once and then stripping and putting them into a list like this:

```
import sys
lines = sys.stdin.read().splitlines(False)
if lines:
    # process lines list....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `readlines()` method will read the file, and automatically split it into a list broken by newline characters. You can then apply the `rstrip('\r\n')` method iteratively to the list. Alternatively, if you know the newline character (normally '\n' for *nix), you can chain the read and split methods like this: `.read().split('\n')`.

Sample code:

```
file_ob = open(path/to/file,'r')
# Method 1
file_list = file_obj.readlines()
for f in file_list
    clean = f.rstrip('\r\n')
    #do something with clean
# Method 2
clean_list = file_obj.read().split('\r')
# do something with clean_list
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that it is expected to have standard stdin procedures, and I dont know if open(path/to/file,'r') is compliable with the way they want to input the information. Then again I could be wrong, I dont really know exactly what "standard stdin procedure entails"

Comment: @user1998665: "standard stdin procedure entails" reading the input data from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: right, so wouldnt that be different from a file input method, like the one Tauchiss proposed

Comment: @user1998665: Not if there was input file redirection as in `python myscript.py <input_file.txt`. Also `sys.stdin` is already open when the script starts, so using it doesn't need an `open(<filename>)` either.